# Unable to install pod

Tags: ios, cocoapods, xcode9.2

I updated my xcode on 9.2 and then I created a project and installed pod on it. Pod installed successfully but the white file `.xcodeproj` is not created.  Then I ran `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods` and then ran `sudo gem install cocoapods --pre`.

It showed this error:

```
Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: tlsv1 alert protocol version (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

Comment: Try to clean gems sudo rm -rf /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8

Comment: Whats the version of your installed cocoapods? Did you run `pod init` in your workspace? the .xcodeproj needs to be in the root of your workspace and cocoapods will create a `.xcworkspace` for you if your Podfile is setup proper

Comment: btw, gems should not be installed via sudo. `gem install cocoapods` should be sufficient